# 4th year phd in BiomedEngineering - How do I maximize my chances of getting an assistant professorship in my hometown?

Tags: postdocs, engineering, academic-life, work-life-balance

Preface: I know

- how how difficult is to get any professorship
- that i should write really good research papers etc...
- that its not smart to plan on this and only this

My hometown is middle of the country, only 2 universities in my field. 
Help me out, how do I maximize my chances of being near my family and getting my ideal job?

Comment: You should try to generalize this a tad more. For example, instead of "in my hometown" you can indicate in "my preferred geographic location." Some people, for example, might want to go to another geographic location that is not their hometown.

Comment: As to starting off, in your statement of purpose, you can indicate your connection to a certain location as being the inspiration for you pursuing the field.

Answer (score 2):

Take a good, hard look at the research being done in the department, and the specialties of the professors. Are there any subfields where the department is weak? Are there cross-field collaborations that could be done, but aren't? Is there an emeritus or soon-to-be emeritus professor that will leave a gap in coverage?

What you're looking for is a niche that you can fill.

Answer (score 2):

One you've found specific gaps to fill in your own department, take a look at how you could get experience in those areas by post-doccing at a more prestigious university ( or even industry). A lot of selection committees require that candidates have moved around during their training. Also ask your current supervisor what the department looks for when they do selection committees for new professors.

Then take a long, hard look at your situation and decide whether it will even be feasible. You will have less than half a dozen shots at this, and the competition for every one of those will be steep. If your primary goal is to stay in your home town, make backup plans for if the professorship doesn't pan out. Look into becoming a lecturer, or staff scientist, or working in industry in your home state.